# jquery add element to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to add an html code `"<a href="example.com">example.com</a>"` using jquery to a javascript variable of element

```
<body>
    <div id="test"> </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var objTo = document.getElementById('test')

    var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
    objTo.appendChild(contentDiv);

    ---- Now I want to add 
    ---- "<a href="example.com">example.com</a>" element to contentDiv using jquery. how to do it

    </script>
```

Comment: Why using jQuery and not JavaScript? You didn't even tagged jQuery(done that for you) on this question. You do `objTo.appendChild(contentDiv);` ...can't you do the same thing for your anchor?

Comment: `$('.'+altClass).append( '<a href="example.com">example.com</a>' )`

Comment: assuming there is no class name. refer the edited question without class name

Comment: well then just add an identifier...

Comment: that means we cant use the javascript variable contentDiv in jquery

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi, Yes we can use javascript variable in JQuery.

Comment: sorry i mean use it as $.contentDiv.append( --  raw html-- ), is it possible

Comment: I was confused as how you call it `javascript variable` but now I know what you actually mean

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to use JQuery to do this, as others noted. However assuming you are trying to learn JQuery, this would be the way:

```
$(contentDiv).append("<a href='example.com'>example.com</a>"
```

Note that:

1. the contentDiv element must be wrapped with the JQuery wrapper (either $ or jQuery, based on your version)
2. Inner quotes are problematic in this situation, therefore I used single apostrophes inside the element.

Comment: can variables be wrapped in $() as selector

Comment: Yes, variables which hold DOM elements (like contentDiv holds a div element) can be wrapped in $() - and the DOM element will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert the hyperlink into the body?

```
var el = document.createElement('a')

el.href = "example.com";
el.innerHTML = "example.com";

// Append to body.
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Ought to do it without jQuery.

EDIT: If you want to do it with jQuery:

```
let url = "example.com";

$('body').append(`<a href="${url}">${url}</a>`);
```

Although soeone has already given a similar example.

Comment: thats pure javascript way. i want to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the javascript variable in the Jquery function then must use the **$()**.

In your case before appending the created element insert your **'a'** tag and then append it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var objTo = document.getElementById('test')

    var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");

  $(contentDiv).html('<a href="example.com">example.com</a>')       //Here using $() add your a tag using jquery html() function.


    objTo.appendChild(contentDiv);

})
```

And here below is the [Demo Check.](http://jsfiddle.net/r0dba5tm/)